# Comparing "Period A" and "Period B" in DAX

Tags: date, powerbi, comparison, dax

My requirement is for a user to select a “Period A” and a “Period B”, and for a matrix (or other visualisation) to show values for A and B. This is the example PBI book from the SQLBI guys which correctly shows a “Period A” and “Period B” when sliced by a non-date attribute (link below)

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/filtering-and-comparing-different-time-periods-with-power-bi/

[image]

This example is using a duplicate date table for “Period B” and an inactive relationship between this table and the fact (sales) table. The “Period B” measure is defined as:

```
> Previous Sales = CALCULATE(
>      [Sales Amount], 
>      ALL ( 'Date' ), 
>      USERELATIONSHIP( 'Date'[Date], 'Previous Date'[Date] )  ) * [Normalization Factor]
```

However, I would like to show this grid with “date” on the rows, so that I see a “Period A”  and “Period B” for equivalent rows in the slicer. “Previous sales” (i.e. a Period B) in the example below only returns a repeating sum of all the dates in my “Period B” slicer.

[image]

We can assume that the number of days in each comparison period will always be equal, and we would only want to compare the dates sequentially – I.e. day 1 of Period A vs day 1 of Period B.

A mock-up in Excel of the desired solution is this:

[image]

I read a solution here which I got to work but only for one day at a time.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Filter-and-compare-different-time-periods-and-graph-results-with/m-p/600938#M285907

How can I achieve this using DAX in PowerBI?

Comment: From a UX perspective this seems incredibly confusing, surely?

Comment: In what way? As an example - users will generally want to compare specific dates with equivalent dates in the year before. A use case is to look at promotional periods which shift between years with no clear relationship between them.

Comment: Can I ask about the data in the mock-up in Excel that you shared? For the first row, 09/1/2009, Period A Sales Amount is for 09/1/2009, and Period B Sales Amount is for 01/01/2008.

Comment: In what way? Period B has no sales on 09/01/2009 - so what you are showing makes no sense. Prepare to explain this behavior in excruciating detail to all end users of this visualization.

Comment: @Marcus I think you are over-complicating this. Maybe my example isn't clear. Imagine you have two sets of dates. Set 1 (Period A) is 1st Dec and 2nd Dec. Set 2 (Period B) is 22nd Nov and 23rd Nov. I want to show the sales for each as per the format above in my last screenshot.

But I have actually found a solution which I'll post later.

Comment: Your example is clear, I am directly critiquing the mock-up you have included. I fully understand what you want to achieve, but it will not be intuitive at a glance for your end users.

Comment: It would be better to have a separate table with day counts and map the period A/B to a common axis. This avoids the whole period date being associated with aggregations that have nothing to do with the listed date.